# Tikz image or some alternative

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make the below hand-drawn image in tikz but unable to correctly get the connections between the different pair of rectangles as shown in the hand-drawn image.

[image: Image to be drawn in tikz]

The code I have written so far is as below :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, mathrsfs, dsfont}
\usepackage{physics, tensor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing, math, calc, decorations.markings, positioning}
\tikzset{middlearrow/.style={
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{#1}} ,
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-2,-4) rectangle (2,0);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=purple!20] (0,-2) circle[radius=1.5];
    \draw[blue, very thick] (0,-1.98) -- (0.3,-2) to[out=10, in=150] (1.5,-2);
    \draw[cyan,very thick] (0,-2.02) to[out=-160, in=-30] (-1.5,-2);
    \draw[red, very thick] (0,-2.02) -- (0.3,-2) to[out=-10, in=-150] (1.5,-2);
    \draw[RedOrange, very thick] (0,-1.98) to[out=160, in=30] (-1.5,-2);
    \draw[Brown, very thick] (0.3,-2) to[out=30, in=120] (1.5,-2);
    \draw[Tan, very thick] (0.3,-2) to[out=-150, in=-60] (-1.5,-2);
    \draw[PineGreen, very thick]  (0.3,-2) to[out=-30, in=-120] (1.5,-2);
    \draw[green, very thick] (0.3,-2) to[out=150, in=60] (-1.5,-2);
    \draw (0,-2) node  [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
    \draw (-0.2,-1.9) node [above]{$P_{\mathcal{M}}$};
    \draw (0.3,-2) node  [circle,fill,inner sep=1.1pt]{};
    \draw (0.35,-2.1) node [below]{$P_{\mathcal{N}}$};
    \draw (1.5,-2) node  [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
    \draw (1.35,-1.8) node [right]{$B^R_{u}$};
    \draw (-1.5,-2) node  [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
    \draw (-2.25,-1.8) node [right]{$B^L_{u}$};
    \draw (1,-2) node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
    \draw (1,-2) node [above]{$P$};

    % left P_M
    %lower
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-3,2) rectangle (-5,0);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (-4,1) circle[radius=0.75];

    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-5.5,2) rectangle (-7.5,0);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (-6.5,1) circle[radius=0.75];

    %upper
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-3,4.5) rectangle (-5,2.5);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (-4,3.5) circle[radius=0.75];
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-5.5,4.5) rectangle (-7.5,2.5);
    \draw[color=black, fill=white](-6.5,3.5) circle[radius=0.75];
    % right P_M
    %lower
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (5.5,2) rectangle (7.5,0);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (6.5,1) circle[radius=0.75];

    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (3,2) rectangle (5,0);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (4,1) circle[radius=0.75];

    %upper
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (5.5,4.5) rectangle (7.5,2.5);
    \draw[color=black, fill=white](6.5,3.5) circle[radius=0.75];

    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (3,4.5) rectangle (5,2.5);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (4,3.5) circle[radius=0.75];

    % left P_N
    %lower
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-3,7.5) rectangle (-5,5.5);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (-4,6.5) circle[radius=0.75];

    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-5.5,7.5) rectangle (-7.5,5.5);
    \draw[color=black, fill=white](-6.5,6.5) circle[radius=0.75];

    %upper
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-3,10) rectangle (-5,8);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (-4,9) circle[radius=0.75];

    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (-5.5,10) rectangle (-7.5,8);
    \draw[color=black, fill=white](-6.5,9) circle[radius=0.75];

    % right P_N
    %lower
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (5.5,7.5) rectangle (7.5,5.5);
    \draw[color=black, fill=white](6.5,6.5) circle[radius=0.75];

    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (3,7.5) rectangle (5,5.5);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (4,6.5) circle[radius=0.75];

    %upper
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (5.5,10) rectangle (7.5,8);
    \draw[color=black, fill=white](6.5,9) circle[radius=0.75];
    
    \fill[draw=black,fill=cyan!20] (3,10) rectangle (5,8);
    \fill[draw=black, fill=white] (4,9) circle[radius=0.75];

    %connecting different rectangles
%   \begin{scope}
%       \draw plot [smooth] (-4,0.25) to[out=30, in=150] (4,0.25);
%       \draw[thick] (-4, 1.75) to[out=30, in=60] (-5.75,1);
%   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If possible, I would also like to fill up the region bounded by the curves joining the different rectangles with the same purple shade as the central bigger circle at the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here. As I see it, you're not connecting rectangles but circles. Should these tubes be tangential? Do they need to get thinnerand ticker. This is not easy with TikZ since you would need to describe these curves. Maybe the `hobby` library can help. Maybe a nice decoration, similar to [`bent`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.3.2), could also help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for fun and because it is one of those interesting graphics with certain challenges, and although they could be done using inkskape, autocad, but never better than using PGF under tikz or others where you have everything absolutely parameterized. Here is an option using code nesting through drawing definitions and taking advantage of the scope environment, so that only a part of the drawing is needed that is repeated but for which we need to access certain nodes, mirror it, move them, place specific colors. In the end the messy thing was doing the shading, it is done in 2 parts.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\definecolor{GREEN}{HTML}{89CE83}
\definecolor{BLUE}{HTML}{4E7CD1}
\definecolor{ORANGE}{HTML}{E6CAB8}
\definecolor{PURPLE}{HTML}{7A42A2}
\definecolor{ORANGEB}{HTML}{E5C471}
\definecolor{RED}{HTML}{C5575C}
\definecolor{CYAN}{HTML}{7CD0E9}
\definecolor{BLUEB}{HTML}{334A58}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    R/.style = {draw=#1,rectangle,fill=CYAN!30!white},
    C/.style = {draw=#1,circle,fill=white},
    */.tip={Circle[sep=-1pt,black,length=2pt]},
]

\def\PART(#1)[#2][#3][#4]#5#6[#7]{%Code anidation objet called \PART(position)[size][scalex][scaley][color1]{color2}(ID)
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#3,yscale=#4,transform shape]
        \draw(0,0) node[R=black,minimum size=#2](){};
        \draw(0,0) node[C=black, minimum size=#2*0.75](N1-#7){};
        \draw(#2*1.25,0) node[R=black, minimum size=#2]{};
        \draw(#2*1.25,0) node[C=black, minimum size=#2*0.75](N2-#7){};
        \draw[*-*,#5,thick] (N1-#7.135) to[out=-52,in=170] (#2*2.5,-#2*1) node[minimum size=#2*0.3](#7){}; 
        \draw[*-*,#6,thick] (#7.center) to[out=170,in=-66] (N2-#7.110);
        \draw[fill=PURPLE, fill opacity=0.1, draw opacity=0.7](#7.-90-20) coordinate (ST-#7)
            to[out=180-20, in=-110+90](N1-#7.-110) 
            arc (-110:-345:#2*0.375)
            to[out=170, in=15-90](N1-#7.15) 
            to [out=15-90, in=170] (#2*1.55,-#2*0.75)
            arc(-110:120-90:0.5mm)
            to[out=120, in=-100+90](N2-#7.-100)
            arc (-100:-370:#2*0.375)
            to[out=-10-90, in=180-20] (#7.90-20) coordinate (EN-#7);
    \end{scope}
}

\PART(0,0)[10mm][1][1]{GREEN}{BLUE}[A]
\PART(0,-18mm)[10mm][1][1]{GREEN}{BLUE}[B]
\PART(0,-18mm*2.5)[10mm][1][-1]{ORANGE}{PURPLE}[C]
\PART(0,-18mm*3.5)[10mm][1][-1]{ORANGE}{PURPLE}[D]
 
\PART(80mm,0)[10mm][-1][1]{ORANGEB}{RED}[H]
\PART(80mm,-18mm)[10mm][-1][1]{ORANGEB}{RED}[G]
\PART(80mm,-18mm*2.5)[10mm][-1][-1]{CYAN}{BLUEB}[F]
\PART(80mm,-18mm*3.5)[10mm][-1][-1]{CYAN}{BLUEB}[E]
 
\draw[draw opacity=0.7]
    (ST-A) to[out=-20,in=-20] (EN-B)
    (ST-B) to[out=-20,in=20] (ST-C)
    (EN-C) to[out=20,in=20] (ST-D)
    (EN-D) to[out=20,in=160] (EN-E)
    (ST-E) to[out=160,in=160] (EN-F)
    (ST-F) to[out=160,in=-160] (ST-G)
    (EN-G) to[out=-160,in=-160] (ST-H)
    (EN-H) to[out=-160,in=-20] (EN-A);
 
\fill[PURPLE, fill opacity=0.1]
 (ST-A) to[out=-20,in=-20] (EN-B)--
 (ST-B) to[out=-20,in=20] (ST-C)--
 (EN-C) to[out=20,in=20] (ST-D)--
 (EN-D) to[out=20,in=160] (EN-E)--
 (ST-E) to[out=160,in=160] (EN-F)--
 (ST-F) to[out=160,in=-160] (ST-G)--
 (EN-G) to[out=-160,in=-160] (ST-H)--
 (EN-H) to[out=-160,in=-20] (EN-A);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 2):

Just by using the layers, a single path provides, it is relative easy to place blue rectangles in the background and white (!) circles in the foreground. Then the actual path can be placed between them.

In the example below I've added just two simple curves between two circles as well as one connection between two other circles (the one with the black dots on it).

Now you just need to somehow describes the big purple figure with the path operations TikZ provides: [Path Operations](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths), [Curves](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#sec-74.3). Maybe even a [smooth plot](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#pgf./tikz/smooth) or the [`hobby` library](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby?)? A decoration similar to [`bent`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.3.2) could also be key to creating these paths.

### Code

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=2.4cm, y=2.4cm, thick,
  rect/.style={shape=rectangle, minimum size=2cm, draw, fill=cyan!20},
  circ/.style={shape=circle, minimum size=1.5cm, draw, fill=white, outer sep=+0pt},
  bendy/.style={decorate, decoration={name=bent,amplitude=#1}}, bendy/.default=-5mm,
  d/.style={shape=circle, fill=black, inner sep=+1.5pt},
  d'/.style={edge node={node[at start, d]{}}},
  d_/.style={edge node={node[at end, d]{}}},
  nt/.style={edge node={coordinate[at end](#1)}},
]
\draw[fill=purple!20]
  foreach[count=\xi] \x in {1, 2, 5, 6} {
    foreach[count=\yi] \y in {1, 2, 3.2, 4.2} {
      node[behind path, rect]      at (\x, \y) {}
      node[circ]         (\xi-\yi) at (\x, \y) {\xi-\yi}
    }
  }
  (2-4.0) to[bend right]    (3-4.135)
          --                (3-4.225)
          to[bend left=15]  (2-4.-90)
  (3-4.east) edge[bend right,    d', nt=@, Tan] ++ (200:1)
  (@)        edge[bend right=20, d', d_, RedOrange] (4-4.25)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!